# yii accessrules not working 500 internal error and still rendering

Tags: php, yii

I'm getting an 500 error from my production server, and still rendering.
so far that i can go to the error is because of the access rules.
I have this configuration

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('create','admin','delete','index', 'view','update','users'),
            'roles'=>array('SuperAdmin'),
        ),
        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('index', 'view','update','users'),
            'roles'=>array('Admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'roles'=>array('Admin','User'),
        ),
        array('deny',
            'users'=>array('?'),
        )
    );
}
```

my error configuration is following:
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_NOTICE | E_DEPRECATED | E_STRICT));
    ini_set('display_errors','0');

this should be not sending any 500 but still sending. and the weird thing is that it doesn't stop but continue and render the view.

this is how i create the roles
        $auth=Yii::app()->authManager;
        $roles = $auth->getRoles();

```
    if (!isset($roles['Admin']))
        $auth->createRole('Admin', 'Admin', 'return Yii::app()->user->getState("role")=="Admin";');

    if (!isset($roles['SuperAdmin']))
        $auth->createRole('SuperAdmin', 'Super Admin ', 'return Yii::app()->user->getState("role")=="SuperAdmin");');

    if (!isset($roles['User']))
        $auth->createRole('User', 'User', 'return Yii::app()->user->getState("role")=="User");');
    $auth->save();
```

regards.

Comment: Did you check your logs (web server and yii) ?

Comment: web server is fine, i will check yii logs in server.

Answer (score 0):

Some times this happens because you haven't added filter function before access rules

```
public function filters() {
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
}
```

Try this or tell me weather its there

Comment: actually I am using accessControl and I am using like you suggested.
It seems it is not working because it parses some php
    $auth->createRole('SuperAdmin', 'Super Admin ', 'return Yii::app()->user->getState("role")=="SuperAdmin");');